# How to use distributions from packages in rstan?

Tags: r, distribution, stan, rstan

I would like to fit distributions implemented in R packages in `rstan`. I know that one can use custom distributions if they are implemented directly:

https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/stan-users-guide/custom-probability-functions-chapter.html

However, I wonder if one can use distributions from other packages. For example, I want to use the variance-gamma distribution from the `VarianceGamma` package.

```
dvg(x, vgC , sigma , theta , nu )
```

How can I define the log density function, say, `vg_lpdf()` using the already available implementation in `dvg(x, vgC , sigma , theta , nu , log = TRUE)` in order to be able to call this command in the implementation of the likelihood in `target += vg_lpdf(x | vgC , sigma , theta , nu)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, except you can look at the source code of the R implementation and utilize the same logic in a Stan function that you write. It is essentially only possible to call external C++ code, and even then the external C++ code must be templated in order to accept Stan's custom scalar types that enable gradients to be calculated via automatic differentiation.

In addition, the variance-gamma distribution would be difficult to implement in Stan because its Bessel functions can only be evaluated at integer orders. Also, the absolute value operations tend to mess up the MCMC algorithm in Stan, which assumes the posterior log-kernel is differentiable everywhere.

My guess is that it will work better if you use Stan's `integrate_1d` function to integrate out the latent error that has a Gamma distribution (or really any distribution).

https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_23/stan-users-guide/integrate-1d.html

Comment: Many thanks. That is certainly a big limitation as one can only use the models already implemented in `rstan`, rather than utilizing the large catalogue of distributions available and efficiently implemented in other packages.